# Try to execute query in MongoDB using PHP

Tags: php, mongodb

I just trying to config the PHP access to my MongoDB database. First of all, the MongoDB driver was installed in the PHP and it was update the php.ini. The code below works without any warning or error and apparently everything is just fine:

```
$options =  [
    'username' => 'user',
    'password' => '123456',
    'authSource' => 'database',
];

$mongo = new MongoDB\Driver\Manager('mongodb://localhost:27017', $options);
$writeConcern = new MongoDB\Driver\WriteConcern(MongoDB\Driver\WriteConcern::MAJORITY, 1000);

$document = array("key" => "value", "another_key" => "another_value"); //...and so on...

$bulk->insert($document);

$result = $mongo->executeBulkWrite('db.mycollection', $bulk, $writeConcern);
```

But, when I check my database, nothing happened: no document were inserted!!!
What I'm doing wrong???

Comment: where is $bulk defined? Which database should executeBulkWrite be writing to? What commands did you use to verify nothing was written?

Comment: Ooops: before that: 

`$bulk = new MongoDB\Driver\BulkWrite();`

and in my mongodb:

`db.mycollection.find({})`

Comment: That `executeBulkWrite` call is using a database named `db`, is that correct?